# Python imp not finding modules

Tags: python, import, pip, google-cloud-platform

I'm trying to get the Google cloud modules for python working, but am having difficulty in imp seeing the modules correctly for verification purposes. I've even tried a few variants in spelling, but no joy.

I can import the module successfully, but imp cannot verify it:

```py
>>> pip.get_installed_distributions()       
[
    urllib3 1.23 (/home/user/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages),
    six 1.11.0 (/home/user/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages),
    setuptools 40.0.0 (/home/user/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages),
    rsa 3.4.2 (/home/user/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages),
    requests 2.19.1 (/home/user/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages),
    pytz 2018.5 (/home/user/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages),
    pysnmp 4.4.4 (/home/user/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages),
    pysmi 0.3.1 (/home/user/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages),
    pycryptodomex 3.6.4 (/home/user/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages),
    pyasn1 0.4.4 (/home/user/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages),
    pyasn1-modules 0.2.2 (/home/user/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages),
    psutil 5.4.6 (/home/user/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages),
    protobuf 3.6.0 (/home/user/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages),
    proto-google-cloud-logging-v2 0.91.3 (/home/user/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages),
    proto-google-cloud-error-reporting-v1beta1 0.15.3 (/home/user/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages),
    proto-google-cloud-datastore-v1 0.90.4 (/home/user/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages),
    ply 3.11 (/home/user/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages),
    oauth2client 3.0.0 (/home/user/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages),
    idna 2.7 (/home/user/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages),
    httplib2 0.11.3 (/home/user/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages),
    grpcio 1.13.0 (/home/user/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages),
    grpc-google-iam-v1 0.11.4 (/home/user/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages),
    googleapis-common-protos 1.5.3 (/home/user/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages),
    google 2.0.1 (/home/user/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages),
    google-resumable-media 0.3.1 (/home/user/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages),
    google-gax 0.15.16 (/home/user/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages),
    google-cloud 0.32.0 (/home/user/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages),
    google-cloud-vision 0.29.0 (/home/user/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages),
    google-cloud-videointelligence 1.0.1 (/home/user/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages),
    google-cloud-translate 1.3.1 (/home/user/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages),
    google-cloud-trace 0.17.0 (/home/user/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages),
    google-cloud-storage 1.10.0 (/home/user/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages),
    google-cloud-speech 0.30.0 (/home/user/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages),
    google-cloud-spanner 0.29.0 (/home/user/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages),
    google-cloud-runtimeconfig 0.28.1 (/home/user/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages),
    google-cloud-resource-manager 0.28.1 (/home/user/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages),
    google-cloud-pubsub 0.30.1 (/home/user/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages),
    google-cloud-monitoring 0.28.1 (/home/user/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages),
    google-cloud-logging 1.4.0 (/home/user/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages),
    google-cloud-language 1.0.2 (/home/user/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages),
    google-cloud-firestore 0.28.0 (/home/user/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages),
    google-cloud-error-reporting 0.28.0 (/home/user/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages),
    google-cloud-dns 0.28.0 (/home/user/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages),
    google-cloud-datastore 1.4.0 (/home/user/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages),
    google-cloud-core 0.28.1 (/home/user/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages),
    google-cloud-container 0.1.1 (/home/user/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages),
    google-cloud-bigtable 0.28.1 (/home/user/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages),
    google-cloud-bigquery 0.28.0 (/home/user/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages),
    google-cloud-bigquery-datatransfer 0.1.1 (/home/user/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages),
    google-auth 1.5.0 (/home/user/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages),
    google-api-core 1.2.1 (/home/user/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages),
    gapic-google-cloud-logging-v2 0.91.3 (/home/user/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages),
    gapic-google-cloud-error-reporting-v1beta1 0.15.3 (/home/user/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages),
    gapic-google-cloud-datastore-v1 0.15.3 (/home/user/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages),
    futures 3.2.0 (/home/user/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages),
    future 0.16.0 (/home/user/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages),
    enum34 1.1.6 (/home/user/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages),
    dill 0.2.8.2 (/home/user/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages),
    chardet 3.0.4 (/home/user/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages),
    certifi 2018.4.16 (/home/user/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages),
    cachetools 2.1.0 (/home/user/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages),
    beautifulsoup4 4.6.0 (/home/user/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages)
]
>>> imp.find_module('google-cloud')  
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named google-cloud
>>> imp.find_module('google')      
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named google
>>> import google.cloud
>>> imp.find_module('google')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named google
>>> imp.find_module('google.cloud')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named google.cloud
>>> imp.find_module('google-cloud')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named google-cloud
```

I have solved my problem by using another verification method, but I would like to understand what went wrong. Most, but not all, other modules can be verified correctly.

What is required before `imp` can `find_module`?

Comment: It's better if you ask on the library's [GitHub Issue Tracker](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/google-cloud-python).

Answer (score -1):

You need to install google-cloud in your Python  environment.

```
pip install google-cloud
```

Comment: google-cloud is already installed as can be seen by the output of the first line showing `google-cloud 0.32.0`. This method was not returning the correct state.